# Unknown element shows up in may create-react-app Application with Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app

I study react application with Typescript. my problem is unknown HTML iframe HTML element shows up outside the id="root" element in body element of index.html of public folder of the application when the development server is working. Its z-index block all input of the mouse on the application. How can I remove this? could you help me?

rendering file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unknown element in index.html when development server is working.

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <iframe style="position: fixed; top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; border: none; 
    z-index: 2147483647;">
    </iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you use any browser extensions?

Comment: no i don't have any extention.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same problem in my local development machine. I solved this problem. But my solution is a brute-force solution (not ideal or actual solution). I used this css globally.

```
iframe {
  display: none !important;
}
```

[unknown injected iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHhv9.png)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051008/react-injecting-iframe-with-max-z-index-on-reload-after-changes-development