# React hot reload adding iFrame with high z-index, nothing clickable unless dom element deleted

Tags: reactjs

Whenever I make a save and React hot reloads the app, an iframe with a high z-index gets injected which makes the UI un-clickable.

I have to either open up dev tools and delete the element OR I have to refresh the UI for things to work correctly again.

If I delete the dom element, it doesn't attempt to add again into the UI unless I refresh and there's another hot reload. Using incognito or no extensions gives the same result.

[image: iframe and code that's being injected]

Comment: wouldn't be an iframe if you hadn't wanted. Look at your react components, have you searched the z-index number in your project? => ctrl + shift + f

Comment: This looks like exactly your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051008/react-injecting-iframe-with-max-z-index-on-reload-after-changes-development

Comment: @yuriy636 That is EXACTLY what's happening. Thank you!

Comment: Everytime you deal with iframes, there is a high change a "Content-Security-Policy" slaps your face. Keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue you need to add the following to your `package.json` file:

```
"resolutions": {
  "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
},
```

Then install `react-error-overlay` as a dev dependency with `npm i --save-dev react-error-overlay@v6.0.9`. Then remove your **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** file. Run `npm install` and check if that works.

If the issue is not resolved, run `npm install react-error-overlay@6.0.9` again it will solve the issue. More information is available [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773).