# Unexpected iframe injected in reactjs app in dev mode

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-chrome

I've a react app, but most of the time when I do changes in the source the browser reloads the new code, but an iframe is being injected into the app over the whole application

[image]

I've already reviewed my source code, and of course I'm not doing it by myself, also, I reviewed Chrome extensions that I have installed and basically are just these (Copy All Urls, Google Docs Offline, Redux DevTools, Redux DevTools)

and all libraries that I've installed in package.json files are

```
{
  "name": "react-ui-generator",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-table/core": "~4.3.1",
    "@material-table/exporters": "^1.0.12",
    "@material-ui/core": "~4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "~4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@monsonjeremy/react-leaflet-core": "^1.1.1",
    "@react-leaflet/core": "npm:@monsonjeremy/react-leaflet-core",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.0",
    "@rjsf/core": "~3.1.0",
    "@rjsf/material-ui": "~3.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "connected-react-router": "~6.9.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "guid": "0.0.12",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.1",
    "immutability-helper": "~3.1.1",
    "isomorphic-ws": "^4.0.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-ui-nested-menu-item": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "5.0.0",
    "notistack": "^1.0.10",
    "placeholder-loading": "^0.5.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-leaflet": "npm:@monsonjeremy/react-leaflet@3.2.1",
    "react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-simple-oauth2-login": "^0.5.1",
    "react-spring": "^9.3.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "ws": "^7.5.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/*.stories.*"
        ],
        "rules": {
          "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.3.12",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.3.12",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-json-editor-ajrm": "^2.5.13",
    "storybook": "^6.3.12",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui": "^0.9.0-alpha.24",
    "storybook-addon-mock": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

and I don't think that any to these are injecting this iframe.

What else can I review to fix/remove this unexpected iframe?

Because is really annoying to refresh the page manually each time or remove this iframe manually, because is blocking the entire page from clicks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React injecting iframe with max z-index on reload after changes (development)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051008/react-injecting-iframe-with-max-z-index-on-reload-after-changes-development)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Have you checked your console for uncaught errors being emitted outside of your React application? This seems to happen during dev builds when `create-react-app`'s error catching mechanism gets confused.

**Longer speculation**

I've been seeing this as well. This won't be a complete answer, but might help you find the error on your side.

It appears that this overlay is a `create-react-app` error catching mechanism gone wrong. In our case, there was an error being thrown by a `<script>` tag outside of the React application code entirely. It was likely generated and attached to the DOM by the Google Tag Manager SDK:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="">fbq("trackCustom","Purchase Successful - Free");</script>
```

We do fire that particular event, but the implementation details are hidden from our React app. `fbk` is undefined in our dev environment (related to Facebook tracking) and so it throws a `ReferenceError` and the overlay you're describing pops up.

As for why `create-react-app` generates a *completely transparent edge-to-edge empty iframe that blocks all clicks* I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me on every hot reload, preventing inspection of the DOM in Chrome Devtools. When this happens, also a console error is logged `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

My fix was to add this dev dependency

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  },
```

and reinstalling the dependencies.

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11773#issuecomment-995933869